# how to use/migrate a dll (built by me) in silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

I have a class library built on .net 3.5, I wanted to use it in a silverlight project and it told me that I must build it against silverlight runtime, anybody knows how to do this ?

 can I migrate it, or should I create a new silverlight project and rewrite it or something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [Silverlight Class Library](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/building-and-using-a-class-library-in-silverlight-2-0/):

[image]
<sub>(source: [c-sharpcorner.com](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/silverlightclasslibrary07142008225235pm/Images/ClassLibImg1.jpg))</sub>